# addStyle function in openxlsx does not fill cells in excel spreadsheet with the right color

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

Consider the following code block from the r package openxlsx.

I'm trying to fill certain cells in the excel spreadsheet with a particular color.

This is the code I used in order to do this.

```
library(openxlsx)

# Create a new workbook
wb <- createWorkbook("My name here")

# Add a worksheets
addWorksheet(wb, "Expenditure", gridLines = FALSE)
addWorksheet(wb, "Income", gridLines = FALSE)

# write data to worksheet 1
writeData(wb, sheet = 1, USPersonalExpenditure, rowNames = TRUE)

# Create style object in order to fill certain cells in the excel spreadsheet.
Styling_object <- createStyle(fontColour = "red", bgFill = "yellow")

# Add style to cell in row 2 column 1.
addStyle(wb, sheet = 1, style = Styling_object, rows = 2, cols = 3)

# Add style to cell in row 4 column 3.
addStyle(wb, sheet = 1, style = Styling_object, rows = 4, cols = 3)

# save the workbook
saveWorkbook(wb, "testing_add_style_1.xlsx", overwrite  = TRUE)
```

What I don't understand is why the cells that I specified to be filled up in the excel sheet is filled up with the wrong color. I specified the `bgfill` argument in the `createStyle` to be "yellow" which is the fill color I want for the specified cells, but for some reason the cell is filled with a black color in the resulting excel spreadsheet.

This is what I get in my excel spreadsheet.

[image]

While it should look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `fgFill` instead of `bgFill`.  `bgFill` is for conditional formatting.

```
Styling_object <- createStyle(fontColour = "red", fgFill = "yellow")
```

[image]